# bash shell script is putting the last item first when I echo or try to create a command

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I'm confused. Why is the last item being echoed first?

```
echo -e "\n\nPROCESS: cik : $cik companyName : $companyName form : $form date : $dateStr textURL : $textURL ID : $ID"

OUTPUT:

ID : 6f89f534-2c81-4338-89ac-f691c842b8f1LION FINANCIAL CORP form : 40-17F2 date : 2017-01-05 textURL : edgar/data/1000209/0001193125-17-002593.txt
```

It does this for one other attempt to create a curl command.

```
echo curl -XPUT "$ES_HOST/edgar/filing/$ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"cik":"'$cik'","companyName":"'$companyName'","form":"'$form'","date":"'$date'","textURL":"'$textURL'","data":"'$data'"}'
```

which gets printed as

```
 -o /tmp/foo.txt.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000209/0001193125-17-002593.txt
```

WTH is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `$textURL` has a carriage return at the end of it, so the cursor is being moved back to the start of the line before the id is printed

Comment: yep - that's it. fml

used 
```
CLEANED=${textURL//[$'\t\r\n']} && CLEANED=${CLEANED%%*( )}
```
To sanitize the textURL var.